# Eligible for Tax exemption in USA due to shorter stay?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, tax-residency

I have entered in USA on Jul 2,2017 and working in IT. So, in this financial year I will be working 183 days ( Jul 2, 2017 - Dec 31,2017) in USA.

1. Should I pay income tax in USA for this financial year, what is the minimum number of days a person should stay in USA to pay tax - is it =183 or > 183 ?
2. If rule is > 183, I don't have to pay. If rule is =183 days , then I need to pay. In this case , if am leaving country for 2 days in between, my stay in this year will be 181 days, in this case, am I eligible for tax exemption as my stay is < 183 days?

3.If anyone is exempted from tax because of this shorter stay, the whole tax will be refunded via returns or only partial tax refunded?

Any details will help me a lot.

Answer (score 3):

[Taxation of non-resident aliens](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/taxation-of-nonresident-aliens)

There is no tax-free income based on duration of stay. If you earn over the threshold, you will either pay the IRS or submit paperwork that shows you have paid more tax to a government with which they have a reciprocal tax agreement.

The difference between staying 182 days and 183 is that at 183 you are considered domiciled in the USA. You could also be considered domiciled if you stay less than 183 days but do not stay anywhere else longer.